# Show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Big( \frac{1}{t} -\frac{1}{t^3}\Big)e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$

Tags: integration

> Show that
> $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Big( \frac{1}{t} -\frac{1}{t^3}\Big)e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

I try to obtained these bound by differentiating right hand side and writing it as integral of derivative, but i not sure to these is correct.

Any hint or help I will be very grateful

Comment: Do integration by parts twice. What do you get?

Comment: Elaborating Gary's comment, write $$e^{-x^2/2} = \frac{1}{x} \cdot x e^{-x^2/2}$$ and perform integration by parts twice.

Comment: Taking $f=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g'=xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ i obtained $$\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx=\frac{1}{t}e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}+\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$   and now  repeat for $$\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^3}xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Is these correct @SangchulLee

Comment: @JL_Conte Seems good so far, do the intgeration by parts again.

Comment: thanks¡¡¡ @Gary